# How to call a string from a block in another file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, block

Can't figure out what code to put in "05_silly_blocks" to call the string from the block reverser that is stored in the variable result.

```
require "05_silly_blocks"

describe "some silly block functions" do    
describe "reverser" do
it "reverses the string returned by the default block" do
result = reverser do
"hello"
end
result.should == "olleh"
end
```

Also does it make a difference is the block is not stored in a variable like result?

Comment: You need the implementation of reverser method?

Comment: The question was answered below..Thanks so much for your time though.  I know it's probably a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I exactly understand what you are trying to accomplish with the blocks, but if you want to reverse a String in Ruby you can just say `"hello".reverse`.

The `reverser` method would look something like this:

```
def reverser
  yield.reverse
end
```

This is a dangerous implementation however, as it assumes that whatever is passed to the block will return a String at the very end.

Comment: Oh no I understand that.  So The code above calls the file "05_silly_blocks" and it checks to see that in that file if I reversed whatever string ("hello" in this case) was in the "reverser" block from the file "05_silly_blocks_spec".

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear what you're trying to accomplish. The code from your question looks like an RSpec test. If that is the file '05_silly_blocks_spec' then it should test the code in '05_silly_blocks'. If you want the code for the 'reverser' method I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: You rock!  Yeah I get what you're saying about assuming whatever it passed is a String.  Would it make it better to use .to_s before reversing it? I was trying to use the call method..

Comment: Calling to_s won't do much other than to make sure an exception is not thrown. Imagine you have an object that's modeling something like a Car. It's hard to imagine what "reversing" a car would look like. I think you're on the right track in terms of exploring how blocks work but may need to spend some time understanding how to compose functions and object types.

Comment: This link won't give you everything but illustrates a very good engineer explaining what blocks are for: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Lambda.html

Comment: I see.  I'll put those subjects that on the list.  Thanks so much for your time.